# How to edit a Dropdown list in javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I want to edit the drop down list on the selection of the items in the drop down...
i dont want to add a seperate textbox...

Please help me on this...

Comment: more info? exactly what do you want to do to the dropdown list?

Comment: I believe the user wants essentially a "combobox" whereby you can select an item in a dropdown and edit it right in the UI for the dropdown and have it update the dropdown item. I don't know if this UI would be very intuitive to web users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUI [have an example of a combobox](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_combobox.html) built using their AutoComplete control, although it looks quite different from a normal select drop down. I couldn't vouch for how usable it would be either.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible, however you can use various JavaScript UI widgets to simulate this.

YUI has the [AutoComplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_combobox.html) which resembles a dropdown combobox. ExtJs also has a [ComboBox](http://extjs.com/deploy/ext/examples/form/combos.html) that might be closer to what you want. Just search for JavaScript ComboBox on Google.